# Showing the div after scrolling down the website

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I want to set the animation of the element while scrolling down the page. I want to use only JavaScript to achieve that.

I wanted it to work like this: There is no animation, but when you scroll down to second container, the JS sets the animation and the content inside the container is shown.

The problem is, when I load the page, there is no animation (That's good). When I scroll down, there is still no animation (That's bad!) but when I refresh the page with F5 while being on the bottom of the site, the animation shows up but still not showing my element with blue background.

Here is my full code for this part:

```
    <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .main {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        height: 1000px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    .main-inner1 {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: orange;
    }

    .main-inner2 {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
    }

    .main-inner2-container {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
        width: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .main-inner2-content1 {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        height: 50px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    @keyframes FadeIn {
        { from: top: 100%; }
        { to: top: 0; }
    }   

</style>
<script>
    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

        var y = window.scrollY;

        var x = document.querySelector(".main-inner2-container").getBoundingClientRect().top;

        if (y >= x) {
            document.querySelector(".main-inner2-content1").style.animation = "FadeIn 1s linear 0s 1 forwards";
        } 
    });

</script>
```

```
<body>
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-inner1"></div>
    <div class="main-inner2">
        <div class="main-inner2-container">
            <div class="main-inner2-content1">
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm learning JS so it's important to me to not use any libraries :P

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code a bit. You were listening for DOMContentLoaded event which is fired only once  (after the DOM is completely loaded), instead of window scroll event.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
        var y = window.scrollY;

        var x = document.querySelector(".main-inner2-container").getBoundingClientRect().top;
        
        if (y >= x) {
            document.querySelector(".main-inner2-content1").style.animation = "FadeIn 1s linear 0s 1 forwards";
        } 
    }
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .main {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        height: 1000px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    .main-inner1 {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: orange;
    }

    .main-inner2 {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
    }

    .main-inner2-container {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
        width: 200px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .main-inner2-content1 {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        height: 50px;
        width: 200px;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    @keyframes FadeIn {
        from { top: 100%; } 
        to {top: 0; }
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="main-inner1"></div>
    <div class="main-inner2">
        <div class="main-inner2-container">
            <div class="main-inner2-content1">
            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, your syntax for defining keyframe was incorrect. It is

```
@keyframes FadeIn {
    from { top: 100%; } 
    to {top: 0; }
}
```

And not

```
@keyframes FadeIn {
    { from: top: 100%; }
    { to: top: 0; }
}
```

Comment: Oh... thanks a lot, i forgot how to write keyframes. Launching the animation onscroll works, but still my content isn't fading in the container

Comment: for fade in effect you should use this keyframe
    @keyframes fadeIn {
        0% {opacity:0;}
       100% {opacity:1;}
    }

Comment: It still doesn't show the content div. I can see the animation running, but nothing shows up.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... The blue div is showing up and you don't have content inside it

Comment: I mean, it has a blue background, so i should see it on the screen, but it's invisible. Even if I delete background-colors from parents, it's still not visible

Comment: Ohh, I still had a mistake in my keyframes, Now it works just fine, thank you for your help and time :P